# What is inserting "vsts-proxy-installed-indicator"?

Tags: windows, proxy

Something is continually overriding the LAN connection proxy settings on a bunch of (Windows) machines --- inserting "vsts-proxy-installed-indicator". The post at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/tfsgeneral/thread/a643316d-ac7a-4807-9092-96c20f92dd9f indicates that it's a 'third party' issue, but I don't agree --- one of the machines that has this problem has no third-party addons (as mentioned in the article.)

A temporary solution is to clear the setting, but it eventually pops back in. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check this links... this mighe be causing due to running unit test cases.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/a643316d-ac7a-4807-9092-96c20f92dd9f?prof=required

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221351/what-is-overriding-windows-proxy-settings-inserting-vsts-proxy-installed-indica

Comment: The answer on the stackoverflow link here appears to be correct. And since the question really should be on stackoverflow, not going to try copying that answer to here.

Answer (score 1):

I have this happening on my machine, other developer's machines, and on a build server. I believe it is Visual Studio: VSTS = Visual Studio Team System.

I have yet to figure out a way to prevent it, however.

Comment: It looks like starting Visual Studio might be the trigger for putting this entry in place. Testing to come...